# Using Jaxab SchemaGen

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

i am working on Jaxb 2.x and able to unmarshel XML doc in to Java component but when i am trying to  create schema from my existing java classes its not working.

i have gone through the various site with the help of Google but till now not able to get success,if any one have used this functionality in the past or using it can help me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voting to close as the question is too general. Please update your question and try and be more specific

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood : i have marked question as closed

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of generating an XML schema from Java classes:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

Answer (score 0):

After long try i am able to generate XSD based on POJO using JAXB schemagen.In my main class based on which i was trying to generate XSD was refereeing some other classes which was in other packages and i was not able to figure it out how to set class path for these classes but on removing those references was able to get schemagen working will explore now how to set class path for schemagen

Comment: If you are generating a schema programmatically, the recommended approach would be to use the standard JAXBContext APIs instead of the proprietary APIS for the schemagen tool.  Check out my answer to see how this can be done:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297695/using-jaxab-schemagen-closed/4298645#4298645